# How to find gradient and hessian of summation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am confused because of the summation and its implicit form. Could you please help me to find gradient and Hessian of the function given below?

Thanks a lot.

$$
f(x) = \Vert x\Vert
= \left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)^\frac 12
$$

Comment: Please don't give your question in an image, but write it yourself in the text (with mathjax if you can). Also, please tell us what you have tried, or where you get stuck.

Comment: So, the gradient is defined as $\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$. Can you work out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$? And in general $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$? You need to use the chain rule.

Comment: I am confused when I am writing the notations and the correct form of gradient. When I was trying to solve it I wrote as: f(x)= (x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+...+xn^2)^1/2 and from this, gradient should be: df/dx= 1/2(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+...+xn^2)^(-1/2) *(2x1+2x2+2x3+...+2xn). Is this correct? Could you please help?

Comment: Yes, I will write an answer. Btw, that sort of calculations are exactly what you should include in the question another time, even if you think it is wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of close. But you treat all the $x_i$ as if they were $x$. Also, the answer should be an $n$-dimensional vector.

The gradient is $\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, \ldots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$, so we need to work out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$, i.e. the partial derivatives. Using the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^\frac12
= \frac12 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{-\frac12}
\cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)
= \frac12 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{-\frac12}\cdot 2x_i
= \frac{x_i}{\Vert x\Vert}
$$
(Do you see why the third equality is right?) Therefore, the gradient is
$$
\nabla f = \left(\frac{x_1}{\Vert x\Vert},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{\Vert x\Vert}\right)
= \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}
$$
There are other ways to show the result (probably the most elegant using $\Vert x\Vert^2 = x\cdot x$ with the product rule), but this was the most basic way.

Hopefully you can go on and find the Hessian now?

[Hessian hint]: For the Hessian, you need to work out all possible double derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac {x_i}{\Vert x\Vert}
$$
The result will depend on wether $j=i$ or $j\ne i$. In the case $j=i$, you need to use the quotient rule. Also, remember that we already know what $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\Vert x\Vert$ is, which you will need.

If this is too complicated, try the simple case of two dimensions first: $\Vert (x,y)\Vert = (x^2+y^2)^\frac 12$, and find the Hessian for this function, and then try to generalise.

Comment: Since Hessian is basically the second derivative of the function, I took the derivative of what you get at the end and found 1/(2xi) as Hessian. Is this correct?

Comment: @serifegizembaci I wrote a hint in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have convinced yourself that 
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial \|x\|}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$$
Then, recall that, the **Hessian** matrix of $f$ is the $n\times n$ matrix $\textbf H$ with the $(i,j)$-entry given by
$$\textbf{H}_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}\bigg)$$
thus, we will have to calculate the latter in order to give the general input of the matrix.

Using the quotient rule, we see that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}\bigg) &=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg(\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}\bigg)=\cfrac{\cfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}\cdot\|x\|-x_i\cdot\cfrac{\partial \|x\|}{\partial x_j}}{\|x\|^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\|x\|}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}-\frac{x_ix_j}{\|x\|^3}
\end{align}$$
Note that, 
$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j} = \delta_{ij} =\begin{cases} 
1 & \textrm{if } i=j \\ 0 & \textrm{if } i\neq j
\end{cases}$$
Hence, we have
$$\mathbf{H}_{ij}=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\delta_{ij}-\frac{x_ix_j}{\|x\|^3} = \frac{\delta_{ij}\|x\|^2-x_ix_j}{\|x\|^3}$$
as, for example, if $n=2$, then $f$ is given by $f(x,y)=\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and then
$$\mathbf{H}=\begin{pmatrix} \cfrac{\delta_{11}\|(x,y)\|^2-x^2}{\|(x,y)\|^3} & 
\cfrac{\delta_{12}\|(x,y)\|^2-xy}{\|(x,y)\|^3} \\ \cfrac{\delta_{21}\|(x,y)\|^2-yx}{\|(x,y)\|^3} & \cfrac{\delta_{22}\|(x,y)\|^2-y^2}{\|(x,y)\|^3}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cfrac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} & -\cfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \\
-\cfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} & \cfrac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\begin{pmatrix} y^2&-xy \\ -xy&x^2
\end{pmatrix}$$